# Restore assigned user field - Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, integration, user-stories

In a recent integration, I mistakenly cleared the assigned user field in several user stories in DevOps. Is it possible to either restore this information to the affected records, or view the history of the story so I know who it was previously assigned to?

Answer (score 0):

We can view the user story History to find who it was previously assigned to.
[image]